# Do women not have the right to divorce?

Tags: practical-islam, talaq, husband-wife

I thought that Islam gave women the right to divorce but this answer on an Islamic website is saying that women can not. It says that if they wanted to they would have to make a request and take their husband’s permission but they can’t actually divorce themselves. I may be misunderstanding this, can someone please explain?

https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/186325

Comment: Divorce is in the hand of the husband alone. A wife can negotiate with the husband to give divorce i.e. khula or if there is a valid reason a court can force the husband to give divorce and in some cases a court can void the marriage.

Comment: Why can’t a woman divorce by herself?

Comment: It’s possible that a woman could have a good reason to divorce like the husband being unfaithful or abusive but the husband wouldn’t agree to divorce. What can they do in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divorce in Islam has different forms.

Talaq الطلاق which usually is meant when people speak of divorce. This is widely covered in the qur'an and lies in the hand of the husband.

Khula' الخلع which is simply speaking a Form with which a woman can buy herself free from a marriage. A court is usually necessary for the procedure.

And
Annulation or faskh الفسخ which also requires a court. In order to annul the marriage contract.

See also:
[Any other procedure for Divorce for women other than Khula?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25539/any-other-procedure-for-divorce-for-women-other-than-khula)
[If my husband does not divorce me, is it possible for me to divorce him? Can I say 'I divorce myself'?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22858/if-my-husband-does-not-divorce-me-is-it-possible-for-me-to-divorce-him-can-i-s)